# click item in JQuery listview wont download

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, jquery-mobile

I am restyling a plain html page using [Jquery mobile listview](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_list_views.asp)

However, when i click the items in my new list its target is opened as a blank page in the browser instead of downloaded as it were before, if i press show source on the loaded page i see the data content of the file.

I need it to at least set the browser URL to the url of the file so i can download it from an iOS app i am developing, where i override loading the page in a UIWebView. and instead pass the current url to a download and parse procedure.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<font color="LightGray">
<body background="keynote_background.jpg" link="#C0C0C0" vlink="#808080">
<div data-role="page" id="homepage" style="background: #000000 url('keynote_background.jpg') repeat;">
<h1>Work Archives:</h1>
<ul data-role="listview">
<li><a href="http://users.student.lth.se/XXXXX/apps/workout/Extreme.wrk" type="application/work"  download="Extreme.wrk">ExtremeWork</a></li>
<li>Send work to XXXXX@gmail.com to get published here...</li>
</ul>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</font>
</html>
```

My objective-C donwload routine:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[request URL] absoluteString]];
    [DELEGATE loadFile:url];
    if (loadedNowDownloadMode) {
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Work Updated!"];
    }
    return !loadedNowDownloadMode;
}
```

How can i use the listview styling of jquery mobile but keep the behaviour of ordinary HTML anchors, I guess this is the easiest approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery wrongly assumes that the link is an ajax pageload. Adding the attribute below is the solution: `<a href="yourfile.zip" data-ajax="false">Link</a>`